# Mercurial include / exclude options not working

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

I am using Mercurial version version 3.8.4 on Windows 8.1. when I run this command:

```
> hg status                                  
M Program.cs                                 
? asd\gfgfdg\asdasd\asdasd\ghfg.txt          
? asd\gfgfdg\asdasd\erert.txt                
? asd\gfgfdg\ggdfg.txt                       
? asd\gfgfdg\ghfh.txt
```

the output is the same for all of these commands, which it shouldn't be (unless I am misunderstanding the documentation):

hg status -X "**.txt"

hg status -X '**.txt'

hg status -X "glob:**.txt"

hg status -X 'glob:**.txt'

hg status -X "set:**.txt"

hg status -X 'set:**.txt'

hg status -X "*.txt"

Comment: I have just tested it again and it works... strange.

Comment: Try a `where hg` the next time it fails and see if it hasn't started a batch file instead. I know there was an error in earlier distributions where the hg command was a batch file instead, and it didn't always propagate parameters correctly.

Comment: This looks like a bug. It seems it depends which process opens the console. With this extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e84e2cf-2d6b-472a-b1e2-b84932511379 when I open the console (conEmu) from VS then I get the bug. If I open the console regularly then it works.